# Hard Time connecting Hand with wrist

Tags: modeling

I am trying to connect hand with body but whenever i try to do so it only connects vertices, edges , faces of the body not the body with hand. I tried bridge edge loop, Selected Edges then Pressed F, Selected Vertices then pressed F but it in no way join the vertices selected instead it joins consecutive Vertices of body Mesh. [Here is my File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xFcZjTVFYf3aEUCUIAFFBFy8fIeBbLrt/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: hello, are you sure you're sharing the right file? I can't see an arm or a hand.

Comment: Please Check Again i have updated the link. My mistake to share wrong file

Comment: although Bridge loop did not work for my case even after joining both objects but selecting edges and vertices the pressing F works. Thank you and respect

Comment: maybe you first need to clean the topology as I say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your body and your hand are 2 separate objects, you can't bridge their vertices, you first need to join (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) the 2 objects.

Also be careful with your hand topology because it looks like you have overlapping edges:

[image]

Comment: I will keep your suggestion in mind